# Rails - :all scope and meta-programming not playing nice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, refactoring

How could I DRY out the following piece of Rails code? The `type` parameter will correspond to Rails scopes, and I had assumed that `all` would work too ... but it returns an array and my cunning plan fails.

The `if` looks wrong to me, but I can't figure out how to have a `all` scope work correctly; any ideas?

Original code that improperly relied on `all` as a scope:

```
def readable(type=:all)
  StudyAid.send(type.to_s).authored_by(self)
end
```

Working but ugly version:

```
def readable(type=:all)
  if type == :all
    StudyAid.authored_by(self)
  else
    StudyAid.send(type.to_s).authored_by(self)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't try and modify the behaviour of the `all` method because that could unexpectedly change the semantics of other parts of your code and would surprise other people who came to work with your code.

However you could define a named scope on `StudyAid` with a different name e.g.

```
named_scope :every
```

and then your method could become:

```
def readable(type=:every)
  StudyAid.send(type).authored_by(self)
end
```

Minor point: you can use symbols with `send` so your `to_s` call isn't needed.

Finally, I don't think your version is as ugly as you think yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I have decided to go with an ':everything' but as that meant changing the client API (and all existing calls) I was resisting until sure there wasn't a simple trick I was missing. Good catch on the symbol noise; yes, it's not a long method but I was hung up on the original simplicity of just passing off to scopes!

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to use `:all` only, this should probably work:

```
class StudyAid
  scope :all_recs
end

def readable(type = :all_recs)
...
```

P.S. I wasn't first though...

Comment: Yes, I want to use ':all' if possible because (a) it's what people tend to guess and (b) I'm trying to preserve the original client API.